# preg_match get words into text parenthesis

Tags: php

how could I get an array of all the words in parenthesis?

```
$text = 'lorem (try) (table) lorem (try1)'; 
preg_match('/\((.+)\)/', $text, $coincidencias);
echo $coincidencias;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()` and use the nongreedy modifier `?` in your regex to only match till the next closing `)`

```
$text = 'lorem (try) (table) lorem (try1)';
preg_match_all('/\((.+?)\)/', $text, $coincidencias);
var_dump( $coincidencias);
```